# Powershell function returned value changes when I start a PSSession inside

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a simple function that returns $true when a mailbox exists on my Exchange server and $false when it does not exist. The function itself starts the PSSesssion to the Exchange server:

```
function Check-MyMailbox 
{
  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $Identity
  )

  $ExchangeOnPremSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://exchange.domain.loc/PowerShell/ -Credential $MyCredentials -Authentication Kerberos
  Import-PSSession -Session $ExchangeOnPremSession -Verbose -AllowClobber -DisableNameChecking -ErrorAction Stop

  $CheckUserMailbox = Get-Mailbox -Identity $Identity -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  if ($CheckUserMailbox) {
    $ReturnUserMailbox = $true
  } else {
    $ReturnUserMailbox = $false
  }
  Write-Host 'My Variable In Function:' $ReturnUserMailbox
  return $ReturnUserMailbox
}

$MyVariableInScript = Check-MyMailbox -Identity testmailbox@domain.com
Write-Host 'My Variable In Script:' $MyVariableInScript
```

The output I obtain is:

```
MyVariableInFunction: True
MyVariableInScript: tmp_kku2aeae.wyu True
```

I agree to the "True" output generated by the function (which has type **bool**) but I really don't understand why the variable at script level has the "tmp_xxx" value too and, moreover, it's an **array**.
I spent some time on this and I've realized that **removing the Import-PSSession line** (and keeping the PSSession active from the script previous execution), the output is as expected:

```
MyVariableInFunction: True
MyVariableInScript: True
```

I'm totally unable to figure out the reason why it happens. Can someone suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-pssession?view=powershell-5.1), Import-PSSession outputs a System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo object.

To fix your function, add `| Out-Null` to the end of the `Import-PSSession` line

Comment: Thanks Mike. You're right, It works now but, honestly, I still I don't understand why the object outputed by Import-PSSession is returned by function to the main. I'm probably missing some PS foundamental...

Comment: probably [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982926/new-item-changes-function-return-value) answers to my question

Comment: That thread is exactly the "issue".  PowerShell function semantics are interesting.  They make perfect sense for a scripting language, but they work differently than in most other languages.